# How can I store urdu in oracle

Tags: oracle11g

I have a textbox in which user input Urdu. But when data is stored in DB it is stored like an inverted question mark (¿¿¿¿¿¿¿). The data type of column is Nvarchar2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert the data into unicode format either `utf-8` or `utf-16` and store into data base

Comment: how to convert it?? as now I am using ascii code to convert english into urdu

Comment: If your using java then follow this  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4526192/convert-a-string-containing-ascii-to-unicode link

Comment: I am using C# to convert